# How to split string containing non-ascii characters in views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In Python 2.7 and Django 1.8 [postman](http://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/moderation.html) views, I have this function in postman views:

```
def mod1(message):
    print 'message is', message #bob>mary:سلام
    message = str(message) #without this I get 'Message' object has no attribute 'split'
    sndr = message.split('>')[0]
    print 'snder', sndr
    #...
```

Which give this error

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Strangely, I can do the split in Python terminal.

I have also added `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at top of the views.

Appreciate your hints to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Message contains some unicode text.

If you are not careful to print it while encoding it properly, then you will get those errors.

They are because Python by default will try to encode using only the ASCII codec, which cannot handle the arabic characters. Usually you want to tell it to encode using UTF-8 or a similarly capable codec instead.

```
str(something).encode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Using `message = str(message).encode('UTF-8')` , I still get `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)`. Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't said what part of the code is actually causing that, so I'm not sure. You need to fix the encoding wherever that is (and potentially more places, this is a big reason why Python 3 was invented...)